# How to map touch coordinates to opengl object coordinates in android

Tags: android, mapping

I have created a simple square in GLSurfaceView and I want to select that square by simply touching over the screen on that square. For this reason I have converted screen coordinates to opengl coordinates with the help of gluUnProject() method. Now I want to check whether touched point lies on the square or not. But the opengl coordinates I am getting are in the range(-1 to 1) and my square coordinates lies beyond that. So how can I map these opengl coordinates to actual square coordinates? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks